# multiple column search

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using 2 separate searches at the moment, both work fine by themselves.
but I can't figure out how to join the 2?

Result I'm after is, `IF col1 contains word1` AND `col2 contains word2`

col1 contains single words, col2 contains multiple words.

These are the 2 separate queries that work fine by themselves.

```java
String selection = col1+ " LIKE ?";
String[] selection_args = {word1};
Cursor cursor = sqlitedatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, All_Cols, selection, selection_args, null, null, null);

String selection =  col2+ " LIKE ?";
String[] selection_args = {"%"+word2+"%"};
Cursor cursor = sqlitedatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, All_Cols, selection, selection_args, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join them. With AND:

```java
String selection = col1 + " LIKE ? AND " + col2 + " LIKE ?";
String[] selection_args = { word1, "%"+word2+"%" };
```